# Laravel 5.3 Route model binding in Route group with domain

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, php-7

I need to setup Route model binding in the group which defined subdomain.

When I run this code:

```
Route::bind('app', function ($value) {
    return App\Models\App::where([
      'slug' => $value,
    ])->firstOrFail();
});

Route::group(['domain' => '{appSlug}.upman.dev'], function(App\Models\App $app) {});
```

I just get the error message:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::{closure}()
>   must be an instance of App\Models\App, instance of
>   Illuminate\Routing\Router given.

I don't known, how to get it works.

Thank so much guys for any response!

Answer (score 0):

You should define your explicit model bindings in the `boot` method of the `RouteServiceProvider` class:

```
public function boot(){

     parent::boot();

     Route::bind('app', function ($value) {
           return App\Models\App::where([
                'slug' => $value,
           ])->firstOrFail();
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should looks like this:

```
class IndexPageController extends Controller
{
    public function index($domain, App\IndexPage $page = null) {
        //$domain will send first parameter
    }
}
```

to disable this parameter you can use in your middleware

```
$request->route()->forgetParameter('domain');
```